# com.sun.javafx.collections in Java 9

Tags: java, javafx, java-9, java-module, javafx-9

I need to recompile java applicattion, written on Java 8. App use `com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper` class, but when compiling for java 9 error occurs:

```
Error:(3, 22) java: package com.sun.javafx.collections is not visible
  (package com.sun.javafx.collections is declared in module javafx.base,     which does not export it to the unnamed module)
```

Which class I can use instead of `ObservableListWrapper`? Or how to bypass this problem?

Comment: Why are you using that class to begin with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Java9, most of the [`com.sun.*` APIs are unsupported](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F7696E02-A1FB-4D5A-B1F2-89E7007D4096), JDK-internal APIs and they might go away at any time. Also as described in the [noteworthy column](https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow16/sess/1462485593256001c2xn/ppt/JavaFX%209%20-%20New%20and%20Noteworthy.pdf) -

You should plan to move to using the **[`javafx.collections.FXCollections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html)** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use exposed class since Java 8: `ModifiableObservableListBase`.

That should handle all your needs.